# bootstrap modal textarea showing empty alert on click jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have modal popup in loop with database values. In popup there is a reply textarea and i want to post that value using ajax. But i am getting empty value of textarea when i alert value on click event using jquery. Here is my code

CODE:

```
<?php 
$sn=1;$rep=1;
foreach($view_queries as $q) {?>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_reply'.$rep.'" style="color:red;">Reply</a>
?>
<!-- create reply model -->
<div id="create_reply<?php echo $rep;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<form id="send_reply" method="post" antype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="query_id" value="<?php echo $q->query_id;?>" />
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Reply To Query</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<label>Query:</label>
<p><?php echo ucfirst($q->query);?></p>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Reply:</label>
<textarea rows="3" name="mesg" id="<?php echo $sn;?>mesg" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" id="" data-target="<?php echo $sn;?>mesg" class="btn btn-default form_click">Reply</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<!-- create reply model ends -->
<?php $sn++; $rep++; }?>
```

HERE IS THE SCRIPT FOR CHECKING VALUE IN ALERT:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".form_click",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var a=$('#' + $(this).data('target')).text();
  alert(a);
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: You can not use same ID in loop for message. ID must be unique

Comment: when and how do you add some text to the `textarea`?

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría i want to submit form on click of reply button so the thing is i am getting hidden input value when i alert using jquery but i get empty textarea

Comment: @SmitRaval then what should i do to solve this issue

Comment: check my answer. @rudra

Comment: Please have another look at my example code. You should use data('target') instead of data('.mesg'). Also I believe you should use .val() instead of .text(). You could try to console.log $(this) in you click handler, to see if that is actually the button. Then .data('target') should work.

I only just saw I made a mistake. I had .text() instead of .val(), this is wrong. I've updated my answer. You should use .val().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use .val() instead of .text(). text() get's the HTML contents of a HTML element. val() is used for getting contents of HTML inputs.

Also as Smit Raval already stated, id's should be unique.

You could  give the fields an id with and index set in PHP.
So in every loop you increment the index and add that to your id values, like so:
id=`"<?=$index?>_mesg"`.

And in your button do:
`<button type="button" data-target="<?=$index?>_mesg" id="" class="btn btn-default form_click">Reply</button>`

And then in your jquery you can do var a=$('#' + $(this).data('target')).val();

See the added data-target in your button. And the $(this).data('target') in the jquery for retrieving the value of the target data attribute.

Comment: i have a hidden element also so how to get value of that as i am getting same value in the alert box

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on("click",".form_click",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    var a= $(this).parents("form.send_reply").find("textarea.mesg").text();
    alert(a);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

change `id="mesg"` to `class="mesg"` in your loop.Also make sure you don't repeat the same ID in your loop. Change `id="send_reply"` to `class="send_reply"`

Comment: Did you updated all the Ids with class? As I have mentioned?

Comment: can you please try .val() instead of text() ?