# get value of input in modal popup loop using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have modal popup in loop with database values. The modal box contains a form which have hidden input value and a textarea to insert message. I am able to get the value of textbox with the help of stackoverflow.

Reference :
[bootstrap modal textarea showing empty alert on click jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49320958/bootstrap-modal-textarea-showing-empty-alert-on-click-jquery)

But when i alert the hidden value in alert box it does not change according to the loop in alert box. The value of hidden element is changing in loop when i check using inspect element but when i alert it, it is showing same value.

CODE:

```
<?php 
$sn=1;$rep=1;
foreach($view_queries as $q) {?>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_reply'.$rep.'" style="color:red;">Reply</a>
?>
<!-- create reply model -->
<div id="create_reply<?php echo $rep;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<form id="send_reply" method="post" antype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="query_id" value="<?php echo $q->query_id;?>" />
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Reply To Query</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<label>Query:</label>
<p><?php echo ucfirst($q->query);?></p>

<div class="form-group">
<label>Reply:</label>
<textarea rows="3" name="mesg" id="<?php echo $sn;?>mesg" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" id="" data-target="<?php echo $sn;?>mesg" class="btn btn-default form_click">Reply</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<!-- create reply model ends -->
<?php $sn++; $rep++; }?>
```

HERE IS THE SCRIPT FOR CHECKING VALUE IN ALERT:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on("click",".form_click",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var a=$('#' + $(this).data('target')).text();
  var query_id=$('#query_id').val();
  alert(query_id);
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier option is use `data-*` attribute to persist query id as you are using `data-target`

```
<button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $q->query_id;?>" data-target="<?php echo $sn;?>mesg" class="btn btn-default form_click">Reply</button>
```

Then you can easily use

```
var query_id= $(this).data('id');
```

---

Problem with your implementation is that You have not specified ID of hidden field, thus must be getting `undefined` while fetching value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="query_id" value="<?php echo $q->query_id;?>" />
```

To get its value use DOM relationship of current element.

Use [`.closest(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1) to traverse up to common parent then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the element using [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

*Relevant code*

```
var query_id= $(this).closest('form') //target common parent
          .find('[name=query_id]') //target element
          .val();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".form_click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var query_id = $(this).closest('form') //target common parent
      .find('[name=query_id]') //target element
      .val();

    console.log(query_id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="send_reply" method="post" antype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="query_id" value="1" />
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-default form_click">Reply</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @rudra, It should work I have added a code snippet and you can also persist `query_id` similar to `data-target` see updated answer